# Can the Edelrid Pinch open accidentally during belay?

Tags: safety, climbing, belaying

The [Pinch](https://edelrid.com/de-en/sport/belay-devices/pinch?variant=4184339) is a recently released brake-assisted belay device. What differentiates it from other Grigri-style devices, is the ability to directly clip this into the harness. Edelrid is marketing this as a gain of safety by removing one element of the safety chain. However, for those devices the carabiner also prevents accidental opening of the device (it also would, when using the Pinch with a carabiner). To open the device, a button on the side has to be pushed. For me, this introduces the new risk of the device accidentally opening, which would disconnect the climber and belayer and would likely be fatal.

Does anyone have first-hand experience or a test on this risk?

[image]

Comment: Not heard of these until now, but I've just wathed the video. I have to admit, as a happy owner of a Giga Jul, I'm quite intrigued about this. I suggest you watch the video as your understanding of how you release it from the the belay loop is wrong, there is no button. You slide the device closed and a notch engages with a peg. There doesn't appear to be a secondary locking mechanism like a srew-gate, but still, to release you'd have to perform a quite deliberate action of sliding the side plate up again, and I imagine there's a fair bit of force required to do that.

Comment: Watching the videos again, it looks like because of the way the two halves meet, if it was under load it doesn't look like you'd be able to release it anyway as the belay loop itself would stop it opening.

Comment: Ah, I've just watched a third video and that's the only one that references the button to release it. I stand corrected! Anyway, I think my comments above stand about it being near impossible to accidentally release it, espectially with the button in play too.

Comment: The rope work video shows this better than the climbing video. However, I can still imagine someone touching this in a strange way and unlocking it. The big question is whether this will also allow accidental opening.

Comment: Load sharing visualized: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpBRguSAJM4&t=1158s

Comment: @noah Is that really a 40 minute video just talking about this one device? 

Comment: @noah Thanks a lot. It is interesting that they considered the 3-way-movement but did not implement it in the final version. Still, I am a bit skeptical, as we have seen Murphy's law so oft in climbing accidents. The whole mechanism of load sharing seems to rely on the assumption that the device never comes slack.